# Cloud FireStore multiple document with same iD which is the user UID

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I was wondering how can I display more than one document that is related to the same USER UID

[image]

For now My APP is only Displaying one pdf document

[image]

what can i do to display more than one document of the same user???
Im confuse, how this logic should work, is it possible to do this without SQL?

I only know how to get a single document using the user UID.

my code:

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
    FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

    int _currentIndex = 0;

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      final User user = auth.currentUser;
      final uid = user.uid;



      final tabs = [
        Center(

            child: (Scaffold(
                body: FutureBuilder(
                    future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                        .collection('users')
                        .doc(uid)
                        .get(),
                    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.data == null)
                        return CircularProgressIndicator();

                      DocumentSnapshot manuais = snapshot.data;

                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        print('ok');
                        print(manuais.data()['nome']);
                      } else {
                        print('nopeeeee');
                      }
                      return Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                        child: ListView.builder(
                            itemCount : 1,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {



                              DocumentSnapshot manuais = snapshot.data;


                              return Card(
                                color: Colors.grey[250],
                                child: Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                  child: Column(
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      new Image.asset(
                                        'Images/pdflogo.png',
                                        width: 32,
                                      ),
                                      Center(
                                        child: Text(
                                          (manuais.data()['nome'].toString()),
                                          maxLines: 1,
                                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      ButtonBar(
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          FlatButton(
                                              child: const Text(
                                                  'Compartilhar / Download'),
                                              onPressed: () async {
                                                var request = await HttpClient()
                                                    .getUrl(Uri.parse(manuais
                                                        .data()['documento']));
                                                var response =
                                                    await request.close();
                                                Uint8List bytes =
                                                    await consolidateHttpClientResponseBytes(
                                                        response);
                                                await Share.file(
                                                    'ESYS AMLOG',
                                                    'Manual.pdf',
                                                    bytes,
                                                    'image/jpg');
                                              }),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                            }),
                      );
                    })))),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have several documents with the same ID in one Collection: a document ID must be unique across a collection.

In your case, if I correctly understand it, you could have a [subcollection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model?authuser=0#subcollections) for each `user` document, like

```
-- users (collection)
   -- DTB2.... (user document)
      -- pdfDocs (subcollection)
         -- JH8766ng.... (pdf document, with auto-generated ID)
            fields: nome: "PDF1", creationDate: ..., author: .... (for example)
         -- 65rt6b8H.... (pdf document, with auto-generated ID)
            fields: nome: "PDF2", creationDate: ..., author: ....
```

You would query all the docs with:

```
 FirebaseFirestore.instance
       .collection('users')
       .doc(uid)
       .collection('pdfDocs')
       .get();
```

which returns a [`QuerySnapshot`](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#querysnapshot).

Comment: thank you so much, so using subcollection i can display more than one document for each user.

Comment: I changed the FirebaseFirestore.instance as you showed
Now im getting type 'QuerySnapshot' is not a subtype of type 'DocumentSnapshot'

do you know what else I have to change to display the subcollection?

Comment: Have a look at the doc: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#one-time-read

Comment: Cool, glad I could help!